# Traverse through a linked list to find string

Tags: c++, linked-list, traversal

I need to loop through a vector of linked list and check if a node with the string(s) exists. Obviously this only checks the beginning to see if it exists. I want to know how to go through the entire linked list.

```
vector <Dlist *> table; //Dlist is the linked list

int DL_Hash::Present(string &s) {

    int index = djb_hash(s) % table.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < table[index]->Size(); i++) {
        if(table[index]->Begin()->s == s) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what type is `table`? Some your custom type?

Comment: Recommendation: stop with the hash table for now and get familiar with using `Dlist` by itself. If you cannot iterate `Dlist` on it's own, you'll never pull it off inside a hash table.

Comment: @user4581301 the hash table is where the dlist is in the table vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using variable `i` at all, and you indeed cant do something like `table[index][i]`, as you cant index linked list. You only can get first element in list, and immediate next.

First you get pointer to the beginning (iterator would be more fitting). Then check every item for your condition, until you are at the end of list.

```
int DL_Hash::Present(string &s) {

    int index = djb_hash(s) % table.size();
    auto tmp = table[index]->Begin();
    while (tmp != nullptr) { // check if you are at end of linked list
        if (tmp->s == s)
            return 1;
        tmp = tmp.Next(); // asuming you have function to get next element in linked list.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If `Dlist` would have iterators:

```
int DL_Hash::Present(string &s) {

    int index = djb_hash(s) % table.size();
    auto tmp = table[index]->begin();
    while (tmp != table[index].end()) { // check if you are at end of linked list
        if (tmp->s == s)
            return 1;
        tmp++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or even better, using range for

```
int DL_Hash::Present(string &s) {

    int index = djb_hash(s) % table.size();
    for (auto &tmp : table[index]) {
        if (tmp->s == s)
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```